# Exception: while creating work item in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am using WorkItemTrackingHttpClient class to create work item in TFS, 
I am already passing AreaId and ItrationId while creating workItem

```
patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
{
                Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
                Path = "/Fields/System.AreaId",
                Value = rootAreaNode.Id
});

patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
{
                Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
                Path = "/Fields/System.IterationId",
                Value = rootIterationsNode.Id
});

WorkItem result = workItemTrackingHttpClient.CreateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, teamProjectReference.Name, "Task").Result;
```

But I am facing exception as :
New work item updates must specify Area and Iteration node ids. Parameter name: workItemUpdates

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: You have to pass the area and iteration name as string directly instead of passing ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "/Fields/System.AreaPath" and "/fields/System.IterationPath" with full path instead of "/Fields/System.AreaId" and "/Fields/System.IterationId". Because AreaId and IterationId based on System.AreaPath and System.IterationPath values.

Values for area and iteration paths you may find on work item form. You may create new work item and get default values:
[image]

Comment: changed as per suggestion but no luck, path to be changed to /Fields/System.AreaPath and /fields/System.IterationPath and value will be same as ID correct?

Comment: No, you have to set a string value. By default it has a root value - "TeamProjectName".

Comment: Where I can get this string value?

Comment: Can you update your code sample and share that changes?

Answer (score 0):

There are no `/Fields/System.AreaId` or `/Fields/System.AreaId` fields. You can only use `System.AreaPath` and `System.IterationPath`. Check the example below:

```
"System.AreaPath": "TestCase\\windows app",
"System.IterationPath": "TestCase\\Release 1\\Sprint 1",
```

Comment: where I can get this path value?

Comment: This value is defined by yourself, you could go to `http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/teamProject/_admin/_work` to define area and iteration. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/about-areas-iterations?view=vsts

Comment: How do you specify "System.AreaPath" and "System.IterationPath"? Can you share them? Also, have you defined the Area path and Iteration path as I mentioned in comment? Could you also share a screenshot of the Area path and Iteration path you defined? The screenshot is as this link shows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/about-areas-iterations?view=vsts.